# Verbo per "raggiungere un oggetto posto in alto"

Tags: verbs, word-choice

A volte succede che mi manchi il vocabolario giusto per esprimere fatti della vita quotidiana. Sono andata a un piccolo supermercato italiano che si trova nella mia città. Siccome i commessi sono italiani, ho cercato di parlare nella lingua del dolce sì. Volevo comprare una bottiglia di limoncello, ma questa si trovava su uno scaffale molto alto e, per di più,  un po' indietro, in modo da non riuscire a prenderla con le mie mani. In catalano avrei detto "no arribo a l'ampolla" ("ampolla" significa "bottiglia"), in castigliano "no llego a la botella" e in inglese credo che questo sia "I can't reach the bottle".  Quale verbo dovrei usare per esprimere questa stessa idea in italiano?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potresti dire, in modo simile al catalano:

> Non **arrivo** alla bottiglia

oppure

> Non **riesco a prendere** la bottiglia

Personalmente troverei meno frequente e spontaneo (seppur grammaticalmente e sintatticamente corretto) dire:

> Non **riesco a raggiungere** la bottiglia

perché in questo caso l'obiettivo è prenderla.